# Function to read csv string

Tags: python, csv

This question is duplicate of a now deleted [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880308/function-to-take-a-string-input-and-return-a-table?noredirect=1#comment121731934_68880308) now edited as per the comments provided in the original.

I am trying to create a function which takes a string input in CSV format. For example `"id,name,age,score\n1,Jack,NULL,12\n17,Betty,28,11"`.

It should return the follow table:

| id | name | age | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | NULL | 12 |
| 17 | Betty | 28 | 11 |

It should also remove the defective rows. A defective row is when it has value `NULL` in all capital letters — any other characters like (0 to 9 or a to z or A to Z) are acceptable.

The final output from the above input string should be:

| id | name | age | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | Betty | 28 | 11 |

Here is my code using `pandas` and `csv` packages. I need to create this without using any of these packages.

```
def test(S):
    result = pd.DataFrame(csv.reader(S.splitlines()))
    new_header = result.iloc[0]
    result = result[1:]
    result.columns = new_header 
    df = result.select_dtypes(object)
    new_result = ~df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('NULL')).any(axis=1)
    f_result = result[new_result]
    return f_result
```

Comment: Please do not repost a question! Wait for it to be reopened after editing.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that someone will take the time to reimplement these libraries for you just because you can't or don't want to use them. You'll have to try it yourself and ask specific questions about specific problems you'll face along the way

Comment: Please try it first and then ask your question. Do you want to write in python?

Comment: "The final output from the above input string should be" A rendered markdown table is not a sensible output for Python, especially not without packages. What exactly is the desired output? Which features can you use if even the built-in csv module is forbidden? What problem do you have just splitting the input manually? Which csv features do you have to support, e.g. quotes or multi-line values?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I reopened this question because the odds of the other ever being reopened are next to none — just doesn't happen here very often and the OP *did* add their attempt (sort of).

Comment: mkpisk: Most of what you want to do is relatively easy, however what do you mean by "return a table"? What's a table?

Comment: @martineau, I meant it as table format. But after reading all your comments the output format can be anything which looks like it (it can be a markdown or array)

Comment: @martineau,thanks for reopening the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do what you say you want. Your description of the desired "table" output is somewhat vague, so I made my best guess.

```
def get_rows(data):
    rows = []
    for line in data.splitlines():
        fields = line.split(',')
        if not any(field == 'NULL' for field in fields):  # Not defective row.
            rows.append(fields)
    return rows


csv_string = 'id,name,age,score\n1,Jack,NULL,12\n17,Betty,28,11'
rows = get_rows(csv_string)

# Find longest item in each column.
widths = [max(len(item) for item in col) for col in zip(*rows)]

# Create a row of separators and make it the second row of the list.
separator_row = [width*'-' for width in widths]
rows.insert(1, separator_row)  # Insert following header row.

# Create a format specification for rows of table.
field_specs = [f' {{:{width}}} ' for width in widths]
format_spec = '|' + '|'.join(field_specs) + '|'

# Print formatted data.
for row in rows:
    print(format_spec.format(*row))
```

Plain text sample output:

```
| id | name  | age | score |
| -- | ----- | --- | ----- |
| 17 | Betty | 28  | 11    |
```

Comment: the output format is exactly what I am looking for. I tried it like this ```def test(s):
    o = []
    for line in s.splitlines():
        if "NULL" in line:
            continue
        words = line.split(",")
        o.append(words)
    return o``` but couldn't get the desired format.

Comment: That's not bad, but a potential problem with `if "NULL" in line:` is that would reject `1,Jack,notNULL,12` even though technically it shouldn't — although it's probably very unlikely there would ever be any real data like that.